# Como encontrar determinadas palavras dentro de uma string em C#

Tags: c#

Por Exemplo:

```cs
string query = "INSERT INTO Recibos (idRecibo, DataRecibo, NomeCliente, Valor, CPFCliente, EnderecoCliente, NumeroCliente, BairroCliente, Importancia, Referente, Cidade, UF, Emitente, EnderecoEmitente, NumeroEmitente, BairroEmitente, CPFEmitente, RG) VALUES (" +
                        "@idRecibo," +
                        "@dataRecibo," +
                        "@nomeCliente," +
                        "@valor," +
                        "@cpfCliente," +
                        "@endCliente," +
                        "@numCliente," +
                        "@baiCliente," +
                        "@importancia," +
                        "@referente, +" +
                        "@cidade," +
                        "@uf," +
                        "@emitente," +
                        "@endEmitente," +
                        "@numEmitente," +
                        "@baiEmitente," +
                        "@cpfEmitente," +
                        "@rg)";
```

Eu gostaria de fazer um método que conseguisse varrer toda a string e me retornasse todas as palavras que são precedidas pelo símbolo @ (com ele incluso).

Comment: A palavra `Simbolo`  faltou acento. E editei e deixei a visualização do código mais bonito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo comentário que você fez na resposta da @Catarina Batista, entendi que você gostaria de criar um método personalizado para buscar todos os parâmetros da sua query e depois customizar da sua maneira.

Fiz um método baseado na sua descrição, mas não posso te afirmar se está feito da melhor maneira.

```
public static List<string> ReturnAllParameters(string query)
{
    var parameterName = new StringBuilder();
    var parameters = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < query.Length; i++)
    {
        if (query[i] == '@')
        {
            do
            {
                parameterName.Append(query[i]);
                i++;
            } while (char.IsLetterOrDigit(query[i]));

            parameters.Add(parameterName.ToString());
            parameterName.Clear();
        }
    }

    return parameters;
}
```

Depois chame o método e irá ter uma lista de `string` com todos os parâmetros da sua query.

```
var parameters = ReturnAllParameters(query);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo. O que eu queria mesmo era um método (personalizado) para varrer tudo que eu desejasse. Creio que o método que você fez irá me ajudar com isso. Muito obrigado pelo retorno e pelo método.

Comment: Que bom que pude te ajudar! Se a resposta realmente foi útil para você e te ajudou a resolver seu problema, poderia marcar como resposta aceita para ajudar outras pessoas a reconhecerem que ela é útil? Obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, acredito que se performance for uma preocupação sua, seria mais interessante - e sucinto - utilizar um Regex para esta busca.

A resposta do @Pedro Paulo é interessante, porém utiliza vários processos que podem ser otimizados com o uso do Regex.

```
    static List<string> BuscarPalavras(string consulta, string regex = @"(?<!\w)@\w+")
    {
        var resultado = new List<string>(); 
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(consulta, regex))
            resultado.Add(match.Value);

        return resultado;
    }
```

Cada `if` e `for` removidos são complexidade a menos na aplicação.
Dessa forma a função tem duas entradas, sua consulta e o padrão do regex que já vem com valor default se tornando um parametro opcional, mas que pode ser modificado para buscar outros tipos de palavras. E um valor de saída apenas, no caso a lista de palavras.

Se tiver dificuldade com Regex, você pode jogar o valor que está no código no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) que ele vai te explicar o que ele ta fazendo com mais detalhes, e você pode até modificá-lo.

Comment: Na verdade regex é custosa, pois internamente ela tem que manter várias estruturas internas para funcionar (talvez nesse caso, a performance seja até pior que "o `if` e o `for`", mas só testando pra saber - se bem que para strings pequenas nem deve fazer muita diferença). No seu caso, vc ainda usou *lookbehind*, que a torna mais custosa ainda... [Veja a quantidade de passos executados](https://regex101.com/r/2ijgIO/1/debugger) - talvez dê para simplificar para `"@\w+`, que melhora um pouco - [veja como a quantidade de passos diminui](https://regex101.com/r/2ijgIO/2/debugger)

Comment: É verdade que com regex o código fica mais "sucinto", mas isso não quer necessariamente dizer que está mais eficiente. Engine de regex é um negócio complexo, basta ver o [código fonte](https://vcs.pcre.org/pcre2/code/trunk/src/) da engine mais utilizada atualmente (na qual a maioria das linguagens *mainstream* se baseiam) para ver que na verdade vc só delegou a complexidade para uma API. Mas nada garante que a performance será melhor. Não me entenda mal, eu gosto muito de regex, mas afirmar que a performance vai melhorar é um equívoco, só dá pra garantir se testar muito...

Comment: Não levei a mal não! Na minha visão usar o regex parecia mais interessante, mas claro, necessita de testes sim! Ainda estou aprendendo a usar direito, então esses detalhes feito o _lookbehind_ me passam desapercebido. Mas valeu pelo toque!

Comment: É, regex é um assunto bem complexo e quanto mais eu estudo, mais eu percebo que não sei nada... Mas em linhas gerais, o normal da regex é ir avançando na string, e [só voltar quando necessário](https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/3179/what-causes-backtracking-). Mas ao usar lookbehind, vc força ela a voltar toda hora, já que a ideia do lookbehind é justamente verificar o que tem antes da posição atual. Por isso demora mais, e nesse caso específico acho que nem precisaria usar...

Comment: Quero agradecer a todos pelas explicações e pelo método criado. Vou testar os métodos criados por vocês para verificar qual o mais rápido e o que melhor atende as minhas necessidades.

Comment: O método funcionou muito bem. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei um pouco confusa em relação à sua pergunta, mas caso esteja a referir-se a substituir esses parametros por variaveis é, (com mysql):

```
static public MySqlCommand Command { get; set; }


Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idRecibo", nomeVariavel);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas, já uso o "Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idRecibo", nomeVariavel);". Eu gostaria de criar o método para ser utilizado em outras situações.